# Mystery ruby syntax (with "string" do)

Tags: ruby

I'm doing some work on [a third-party project](https://github.com/archivesspace/archivesspace/blob/master/backend/app/converters/ead_converter.rb#L97). The `self.configure` block is enormous, and contains a number of `with` statements, e.g.:

```
def self.configure

    with 'ead' do |node|
        make :resource
    end

    ignore 'titlepage'

    with 'archdesc' do 
        # etc
```

This looks like a switch statement somehow built into the method's argument section, but I've never seen that syntax before. Anyone here know what is going on?

Comment: It is a DSL.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language  Very common.  See Rspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a method taking a string and a block:

https://github.com/archivesspace/archivesspace/blob/fb860a81f70a98eb489564b6e17d2c120c40fc5f/backend/app/converters/lib/xml_sax.rb#L25

It's defining XML tag handlers:

```
def with(path, &block)
  define_method(handler_name(path), block)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a method taking `"ead"` as an argument, and a block.